# Ember App Kit CORS

Tags: ember.js, express, cors

I'm using Ember App Kit trying to build an application that logs into an existing server.
My problem is that I'm getting the following message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.server.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've Googled this around and it seems that I need to add/enable CORS in my express-server.
I've tried following various samples, such as:

1. https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors
2. https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors
3. http://bannockburn.io/2013/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-with-a-node-js-express-js-and-sencha-touch-app/

But I couldn't get it to run.

In short I'm trying to find a sample of how should I add the CORS onto my express-server

Cheers,

Dror

Comment: Are you allowing jQuery to make the cross domain ajax call.     `$.ajaxSetup({crossDomain: true});`

Answer (score 1):

Stick this inside your Em.Application.extend, inside the ready hook

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, settings) {
  settings.xhrFields = {
    withCredentials: true
  };
});
```

For express, try using the cors module on npm. https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors. It should all work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I dodged the bullet by using an already running server to serve my ember project.

Thank you kiwiupover and ulisesrmzroche for a timely response